# AMC $12A$ Problem (Sequence lengths)

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, combinatorics, contest-math

> For each positive integer $n$, let $S(n)$ be the number of sequences of length $n$ consisting solely of the letters $A$ and $B$, with no more than three $A$s in a row and no more than three $B$s in a row. What is the remainder when $S(2015)$ is divided by 12?

I know the solution, but I don't completely understand it. The relation:

$$s(n) = s(n-1) + s(n-2) + s(n-3)$$

Is made, but I dont see how.

$s(n)$ is the number of sequences of length $n$. $s(n-1)$ is the number of sequences with the length $n-1$, and so on.

How does the sum of $s(n-a)$ for $a = 1, 2, 3$ give the length, $s(n)$? I don't see how the relation is formed?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Taking a valid sequence of length $n$, what do you get when you remove the last block of consecutive letters?
Hence, conclude that

$$ s(n)  = s(n-1) + s(n-2) + s(n-3)$$

Comment: Is the answer 8?  I expanded the generating function: (1+x+x^2+x^3)/(1-x-x^2-x^3) using Mathematica.  How would you get the answer without a computer?

Comment: @GeoffreyCritzer Note you we only need the answer mod 12. So, simply list it out mod 12, and find out the period.

Comment: I found that the sequence (mod 12) has a period of 52. So the 39th term in the sequence (which is 8) is equal to the 2015th term.  Is there a reason to be certain that a sequence like this will always "repeat" under some modulus?

Comment: @GeoffreyCritzer Yes, every recurrence relation will eventually repeat modulo any number $n$. Proof: If it is recurrence on $k$ terms, consider the first $n^k+k$ terms mod $n$. There must be some string of $k$ of them which are identical. From this string, by the linear recurrence, each subsequent term is identical. Note: It is much faster to apply Chinese Remainder Theorem and work on this mod 3 and mod 4 separately (then to figure out the period is 52).